# Bootable dual os flashdrive?

Tags: dual-boot, usb-drive

I want to completely erase my hard drive and start again,

I want to install both ubuntu (11.04) and Windows 7.

I have the iso for both.

Because I do not have any DVD's I want to do this using my only usb drive.

I do not want to have to install an OS from the flashdrive, then go into it and write the second OS to the flash drive, so

Is it possible to make a bootable flash drive that I can choose to install either windows or ubuntu?

Comment: Note that I dont want to run a live OS from this flashdrive, simply install the OS's

Comment: use unetbootin to create the liveusb of Ubuntu, i don't know how to make  bootable usb with windows though.

Comment: Having tried to do this once with Windows, my strongest recommendation is: don't. Buy an external DVD drive for ~30 dollars and save yourself the headaches. It's very easy to do with Ubuntu, however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a bootable USB with multiple ISO images in it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

- YUMI? (requires windows) http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/
- SARDU? (requires windows) http://www.pendrivelinux.com/sardu-multiboot-usb-creator-windows/
- MultiSystem? http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/

Answer (score 0):

READ ALL INSTRUCTIONS BEFORE TRYING THIS

To install windows to you hard drive, I recommend following these instructions here : [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

But those won't help you install ubuntu without a cd. This should.

1. Install rEFIND. Just look them up, you'll find them. Do this from windows when you've installed it with the above instructions. Or if you have an OS on your computer you can use, install it there.
2. You need to make a partition on your computer (1-2gb) or on another usbdrive to install linux to your hardrive.
3. Download and use UNetbootin or Pendrivelinux (look them up to), though I haven't tried Pendrivelinux. Use it to put ubuntu onto the partition you made on your computer, so you can install it from there to your hard drive. (You can't install a linux distro into the device you are running it from 99% of the time)
4. The option to run Ubuntu should show up from the boot menu if you've installed reFIND correctly. Boot it.
5. Use the installer to install onto your hard drive.

Tips
-you can't actually install Ubuntu onto your hard drive with UNetbootin or Pendrivelinux. What your basically doing is installing a "demo". However, you can install Ubuntu from one device to a seperate one. That's why you need to put Ubuntu onto your computer partition first, then use that "demo" to install to your hard drive.