# How to create a Windows installation USB in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, usb

I have the need to create a Live USB to install Windows but from Ubuntu, I've tried to emulate the tools that make the same function from windows but I just do not work.

I would be very helpful to know how. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Following the guide from [THIS](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/) link

Just download MultiBoot from here: http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2

Decompress it. Run the `install-depot-multiboot.sh` from the terminal and follow the instructions. You should see the program in Applications -> Accessories -> MultiSystem (And even a MultiSystem for Virtualbox)

Then just run the program and follow the steps in it. Already tested Windows XP, Ubuntu and Windows 7.

For more info read this post: [How to create a bootable USB with multiple ISO images in it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it)

Comment: `$ sudo ./install-depot-multisystem.sh`
 Error: xterm

Answer (score 13):

There is a two-click possibility using [WinUSB](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/tool-to-create-windows-usb-install.html).

**2017 UPDATE**: WinUSB has been forked to WoeUSB, which supports Windows 10. [See a guide here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/create-bootable-windows-10-usb-ubuntu).

[image]

To install WinUSB, execute the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

I have tested this in 12.04 and 12.10.

Comment: Note: This works for Windows Vista and up. ("Supported images: Windows Vista, Seven, 8 installer for any language and any version (home, pro...) and Windows PE.")

Comment: ppa is not available by this time.2

Comment: Instaed of "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight" use "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8" colingille repo is not working. You will get error in step 3.