# Make ubuntu usb bootable on windows

Tags: windows, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)
>   [How to create a live usb for Windows in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47362/how-to-create-a-live-usb-for-windows-in-ubuntu)

I know there are a lot of tools to create a bootable usb for ubuntu with windows.

But I'm sure, that there was a possibility in the ubuntu installation directory. I used it some time ago, but I can't find it anymore :(

I think it was a .exe, or a .bat, any case a cmd window has opened, some things were executing and the usb was bootable. And it was in the ubuntu directory!

Is there still the possibility to do that? Does that file exist? I unfortunately can't remember.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Do you want to install Ubuntu from within Windows? Do you want to create a live USB from within Windows, that can be later used to boot or install Ubuntu directly, without booting Windows first?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here, please elaborate yout question

Comment: See [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). That explains how to use Windows to write an Ubuntu ISO image to a USB flash drive. You can then boot from the USB flash drive to try and/or install Ubuntu. Then see [these installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest) and, for more information, [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/22949). *The Ubuntu ISO doesn't contain a tool to make a live USB from Windows.*

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net).

Download the correct iso file. run Unetbootin and follow instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know that there exists such a tool. But I was sure that there is also such a possibility on the ubuntu image :S