# How to make a windows 7 installation usb in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

How can i make a windows  installation USB? I already have the iso file, and i need to install windows 7 dual boot as i have to install my company software.

I am using netbook.

I used unetbootin, but failed.

Any quick and easy solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install a software for this purpose known as winUsb using following commands

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install winusb`

else download a .deb file from [this link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/pool/main/w/winusb/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb)
and then run following command

`sudo dpkg -i [filename].deb`
if you get any dependency problem or errors due to dependency problems use following command to resolve it

`sudo apt-get install -f`

check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) for more info on .deb packages

you can check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47362/how-to-create-a-windows-installation-usb-in-ubuntu) link

for more details on installation and winusb check [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/tool-to-create-windows-usb-install.html) website

Comment: Good answer, this worked for me.

Comment: @bleeves - Thanx btw why do you need a live usb for windows installations??

Comment: Some laptops do not have CD drives. Also I did not ask the question.

Comment: i need to install my company softwares.. it cannot be installed on ubuntu.. by the way, i try the winusb, but it failed, stated that unable to locate

Comment: @ShahRizan- have you tired http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ and can you give full error description

Comment: @Creator can is use yumi in ubuntu?

Comment: yes you can use yumi check for the debain package and install it manually

Comment: yumi nor working.. cannot boot as usual... @creator

Answer (score 0):

If you have the iso image you can use the dd command in terminal, check this link: [Burning a ISO image to USB device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-iso-to-a-usb-device)