# Ubuntu will not install from a USB device on a Compaq machine with Windows 8.1

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

This is my first time trying to install Ubuntu.

The version is 17.10. The machine has Windows 8.1 64-bit. It's a Compaq computer.

I am able to boot Ubuntu and run it off of the USB, but when I try to install it, I go through the steps, up until where, I assume, it is downloading what it needs. Unfortunately, I can not post images, but basically, it says that it is getting time from a time network server, and in the little terminal box, it loops this message:

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:17:
Warning: Source ID 64611 was not found when attempting to remove it
Glib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
```

Now, it doesn't just loop this message. The terminal seems to collect any information into it that I do on the PC, as well as the info that it is collecting from its installation.

I am using my school's wifi, so I don't know if that might be a problem or not.

I've tried searching online, but that didn't help. What should I try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Windows installation USB in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47362/how-to-create-a-windows-installation-usb-in-ubuntu)

Comment: You can do the install without downloading anything -- try that first. Then deal with any wireless problems from a running Ubuntu system.

Comment: @NIMSHAN That duplicate is about creating a USB to install Windows, however this question is about installing Ubuntu, not Windows therefore it is not a duplicate of that question and your erroneous comment should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Your school's wifi is timing out when trying to download the 1.5 GB Ubuntu 17.10 .iso file. Depending on the speed of your internet connection downloading a file this large can take a long time. You need an internet connection that does not time out, for example at an internet cafe, and then save the Ubuntu .iso file locally to a disk or storage device. Then prepare the Ubuntu installation media like this: [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso).