# How to install multiple linux os on a single cd/dvd?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, dvd

I don't have any empty DVDs, but I have one with enough free space. It currently has Zorin os 8 installed on it, which is 1.6 gb iso file. I would like to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it as well, so I can install it on Zorin os 8. Is that possible?

Comment: Is it a DVW-RW? If not ... you know what a "read-only" medium is?

Comment: No, It is  DVD-R. Yes, I know what a "Read-only" Medium is. But before I burned the DVD, I checked an option to let the DVD open to add other files later.

Comment: This may have an answer already here: [How to create a bootable USB with multiple ISO images in it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it). With DVDs, etc, once burnt it is impossible (or very difficult) to add more data onto the DVD.

Comment: what is your purpose of having OS installed on DVD-R?

Comment: Not possible. "Add files later" means "do not close session" or "format the CD as [UDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format)". It means you can "add files later", not that you can later burn a whole new ISO file later.