# two iso on the same pendrive?

Tags: system-installation

if I use Gparted can I create two partitions on my 4gb pendrive?

and then can I make each of these two partitions becoming one an installer* for Ubuntu and the other one the installer for puppy Linux? (or any other distribution?)

*installer= I don't remember the exact word for this.

Comment: Here how about this http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: Using 2 different partitions is the wrong direction. Use GRUB and loop mount the iso images: http://askubuntu.com/a/550979/40581

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but only one of the partitions can be set as a boot partition at a time.  (on most BIOSes)

Meaning: if you want to have 2 bootable partitions on one USB stick, you will have to use gparted each time you want to "switch" between the one and the other.

Depending on what you want/need, you could have a look at [Easy2Boot](http://www.easy2boot.com/faq-/how-e2b-works/)