# Will my Live USB stick work if it already has another OS on it?

Tags: system-installation

I'm wanting to install with a Live USB stick, but it already has an OS on it that's run for working at home. Can I have both OSs on it at once and choose which one I want to install?

EDIT: The OS that's already on my USB is Windows 7. Can I put the Ubuntu ISO on that same USB and install it without a problem?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, unless you make a multiboot USB, putting another OS in the same USB will **not** work. You can make a multiboot USB from ubuntu using [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/) or [MultiSystem](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/) or follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it) or [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-multiple-bootable-operating-systems-on-one-usb-stick/).