# Can I install a Live CD ubuntu onto my hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb, live-environment

I have installed and used Bootable USB's to install or run Ubuntu. I want to create say a recovery drive lets say

- `/dev/sda1` is `/efi/boot`
- `/dev/sda2` is
- `/dev/sda3` `/home`
- `/dev/sda4` is the recovery drive with Xubuntu live installed

I use this command most times to create the bootable usb:

```
dd if=/ubuntu-1x.xx.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

It always works perfect boots right up from usb as if it were a dvd. Works great.

My ideal setup is to format the drive gpt and then make 3 recovery partitions

- `/dev/sda1` with Ubuntu live flavor 1
- `/dev/sda2` with Ubuntu live flavor 2
- `/dev/sda3` with Ubuntu live flavor 2
- `/dev/sda4` is a logical drive off same harddrive that will have  all my other partitions.

So now all I have to do is boot live and mount certain partitions I need to install the os or just run live and mount the `/home/username` directory or whatever the case.

Is it possible to boot a harddrive and then install to a partition on the same drive or a logical/extended partition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a bootable USB with multiple ISO images in it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it)