# Create LiveCD on Ext HD partition without destroying other partition's contents

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, external-hdd, live-cd

I've not yet see a way, after searching here and other sites, to be able to duplicate a Ubuntu 16.04 LivCD, onto the partition(s) of my choice, without wiping the whole ext drive clean in the process.

In other words: I have a large drive with data on it but I just want to create a bootable/LiveCD area without formating the whole drive during install.

Utils/apps like Unetbootin and gnome-disk-utulity haven't been a complete answer, but I have them available.

This might very well be flagged as 'Duplicate', but I can't seem to find an otherwise non-destructive way to add a bootable LiveCD partition to the empty space on my External Hard Drive.

I have at least 7G available w/ an additional 9G in reserve, my ISO of choice would be this one:

- ubuntustudio-16.04.4-dvd-amd64.iso

Thx in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to boot the ISO image off the hard drive instead of the slower CD Drive? If so you can do that as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it