# Bootable USB with two images

Tags: fedora

Could I create a bootable USB that contains Fedora 29 workstation and Ubuntu 18.10 desktop live images in the same USB without partitioning the USB?

Comment: How about the program MultiBootUSB?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install a program on the bootable usb that you can boot to, which then lets you boot one or more of the ISOs stored on the drive. Something like MultiBootUSB or easy2boot would be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The easiest way is to download an app for it. I don't have a personal preference, but you can search for  'Multiboot USB' and choose the one you like the most.

Answer (score 0):

Both YUMI, ( https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ ) and MultiBootUSB, ( http://multibootusb.org/ ), work well. Both allow multi OS with persistence. YUMI does not have a 4GB limit on persistence, MBUSB does.

There are other methods of Multibooting that use multiple partitions including UNetbootin and mkusb: [How do I boot an ISO file from my drive using grub2 on UEFI machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines/1025863#1025863) and [How to create a bootable USB with multiple ISO images in it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it/992836#992836)